# Performance of array of jQuery objects

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a global array containing the IDs of elements that I am currently working with.  Every second I run a routine that does stuff to these elements.

```
var ids = ['abc', 'def', 'zyx']

// the following code happens every second
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  el = $("#" + ids[i])
  // do stuff with el
}
```

My question: would I suffer a notable performance hit or improvement to do the following:

```
var ids = []
ids.push($("#abc"))
ids.push($("#def"))
ids.push($("#zyx"))

for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
  el = ids[i]
  // do stuff with el
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have to guess — why not [create a jsPerf test case](http://jsperf.com/)?

Anyhow, this change would greatly improve performance. There’s no reason to reconstruct jQuery objects for the same elements all the time.

My advice: [keep things DRY — cache everything that can be reused](http://speakerdeck.com/u/mathiasbynens/p/faster-javascript-execution-for-the-lazy-developer).

Also note that instead of:

```
var ids = [];
ids.push($("#abc"));
ids.push($("#def"));
ids.push($("#zyx"));
```

You could just do:

```
var ids = [ $("#abc"), $("#def"), $("#zyx") ];
```

This saves a few function calls.

Comment: Thanks, what I wasn't sure about was the overhead of storing jquery objects in an array.

Comment: -1 I have to downvote this, because it would definitely not improve the performance *greatly*. There is an improvement, and it's worth doing, but it's still only barely noticable at best.

Comment: Ok, I can understand maybe not greatly, but it seems to be a preferred method.  Plus I didn't know about jsPerf, so I found it to be a helpful answer.

Comment: @Guffa http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-quickeach On my machine, in Chrome, `$(el)` is about 89% slower (28k ops/s vs. 247k ops/s) than using a cached reference (e.g. `$el`). Bear in mind that OP’s code is repeated every second (!), that there are slower computers than mine, and slower browsers too. Also, in the example code, there are only three elements, but there may be more. If this is not a great performance boost, I don’t know what is.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: That test doesn't compare finding elements vs. cached results, it compares creating jQUery objects from an element vs. putting elements in an already existing jQuery object. I.e. the DOM elements are already found and cached. The test has nothing to do with caching results, but only tests how long it takes to create the jQuery object itself.

Comment: @Guffa The test I linked to only measures how long it takes to wrap a given element (no DOM traversal) in a jQuery object and compares it to re-using an already existing jQuery object. In OP’s case, it’d be even slower, as he does this + the DOM traversal, for each element, every second. Again, if this is not a performance boost, I don’t know what is. “ The test has nothing to do with caching results, but only tests how long it takes to create the jQuery object itself.” That’s exactly what caching is.

Comment: @MathiasBynens: That's what I was saying. You are using a test that doesn't event test what you are claiming, but something completely different. Besides, you are micro optimising, which is never a good place to start. If you do this in a test that actually does something with the element, you will find that only a small portion of the time is used to look up the element.

Comment: @Guffa It’s not “something completely different”, it’s just the most important part of the changes I suggested. The test I’m linking to tests `$el` vs. `$(el)`. OP uses `$(selector)` and I suggested caching that so it becomes `$el`. “[…] test that actually does something with the element […] only a small portion of the time is used to look up the element.” [citation needed] How long it takes to look up the element depends on the selector being used. ID-based selectors (as in OP’s example) are pretty fast. Constructing the jQuery object is equally slow for any single element (after traversal).

Comment: @MathiasBynens: No, the test that you linked to does *not* test `$el` vs. `$(el)`. It tests `$el` vs. `$el[0]=el,$el`, so that is something completely different.

Comment: @Guffa Where do you see a test for `$el` on that page? Anyway, the point is that DOM traversal + the expensive `$` function call is avoided. There are plenty of similar jsPerf tests that confirm this is a performance improvement. This is *not* a micro-optimization, especially if it’s done for multiple elements and repeated every second (as is the case in OP’s situation).

Comment: @MathiasBynens: It was you who called the object "$el", so I used the same terminology to describe what the test really does. Of course caching the result is a performance improvement, but it *is* micro-optimisation to say that it should always be done. You should consider what's done with the element in each situation, and determine whether it's worth the extra complexity to add the caching, and also determine if it's *possible* to use caching in that situation. In this case it's not possible to determine this, as the question doesn't specify what's done with the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You will not see any **notable** performance growth but it is just a good habit - to not request the thing twice, as long as you can do that just once an keep somewhere.

So my final advice: cache jquery objects just once and after that work with array of jquery objects

Answer (score 1):

You would get a slight improvement, as you are moving some work out of the loop and doing it only once.

For just three items and as seldom as once a second you would hardly notice the difference, though. Locating an element by id is rather easy as the browser has a method specifically for that, and creating a jQuery object is not so much work either.

Comment: Sure, it could be as many as 20 or so.  Every little bit helps when we can't control the client's hardware!

Comment: @JeffV: Even for as many as 20 it would not be much work. A recent browser on a decent computer could do it about 1000 times a second. I made a performance test, which shows that the difference isn't very big. http://jsperf.com/precreate-jquery-objects